# How to adapt my PHP Session into an Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I have this PHP code which I'm using to trigger the user log in. For a successful log in, the user uses their registered email and password. My current PHP code allows the username to be echoed on whatever pages use the $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $dbusername. What I'm now trying to do is to adapt this PHP code to put an Array into the 'loggedin' session. I want the array to hold user registration details i.e firstname, lastname, company and email, aswell as their username (dbusername). This is to enable me to echo such details on a 'user account page'

My code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($email&&$password)
{
$connect = mysql_connect("*****","***","**********") or die ("Login failed!");
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die ("Could not connect to Database"); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regusers WHERE email='$email'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows !=0)

{
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

{
$dbemail = $row['email'];
$dbpassword = $row['password'];
$dbusername = $row['username'];

}
if ($email==$dbemail&&$password==$dbpassword)

{
include 'loginIntro.php';
$_SESSION['loggedin']=$dbusername;

}

else
echo "Incorrect Password";

}

else
die ("That email doesn't exist");

}

else
die ("Enter a registered email and password");

?>
```

Then on my 'user account page' I have this :

```
<?php

session_start();
$dbusername = $_SESSION['loggedin'];

?>
```

For the purposes of echoing the username this PHP code works fine, as all I have to do is :  any time I want to display the users username. So going back to my original question - Please impart the necessary knowledge to adapt this PHP code to hold the users registration details so I can echo such details on whatever page(s) use the session in question. Please forgive my lack of knowledge and understanding, I've scratched my head so hard I've got cradle cap - which only babies get, but in this PHP game I'm an embryo. Thanks for whatever help comes

Comment: Please, please hash your passwords… nobody likes websites which store passwords in raw text…

Comment: Your session object is already an array... : `$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $row);`

Comment: So what’s your actual problem …? If you don’t know how to use arrays, go read up on it in the manual please.

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection and mysql_* is *deprecated*! Google PDO and read  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION` is a array

You can simply save a associative array inside of it.

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $x;
$_SESSION['username'] = $y;
$_SESSION['realname'] = $z;
```

or a nested array

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = $x;
$_SESSION['user']['username'] = $y;
$_SESSION['user']['realname'] = $z;
```

### Beware

- You are using deprecated functions.
- There is no validation on data passed.
- There is a risk (looks like 100%) of SQL injection.
- As bwoebi said, you may not save password in clear text.

## Suggested reading

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an Array as a Session variable, you have to serialize it first. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Then you can add it to $_SESSION, and unserialize (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it on the other pages.

Now here are two advices : hash your passwords using sha1 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), and don't use mysql_* functions, which are outdated. Consider using mysqli ou PDO.

Comment: Why the overhead of serialisation ? U can just do this : `$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $row);`

Comment: Don't use sha1 for hashing passwords, use something a bit more secure like the new built-in [password](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) function in PHP5.5 or the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) equivalent if on earlier versions of PHP (> 5.3.7)